# Qlikview - Target missing where no actual value

Tags: qlikview

I have a **fact** table of `Delay` by `Date` by `Category` (and many other Fields). I have another (**target**) table of `DelayTarget` by `Month` and `Category`.

I am currently associating the target table to the fact table on `Month & Category` but when there is no `Delay` for a given `Category` in a given `Month`, then the `DelayTarget` value does not display in my dashboard.

How do I associate the `DelayTarget` to all `Months` in my main dataset - even when there is no `Delay` to report? I think I want to create a Zero value for `Delay` when it is null but I don't know how to do this or if this is the best method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create MasterCalendar to fill gap in dates.

I can give you more detailed answer but the best would be to share you data model (ctrl +T) and some example data from tables (or even better just.qvw)